# Как добавить pagination через javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Как добавить pagination через javascript? 
Я прошу оптимальный грамотный способ, который бы позволил через js со всеми просчетами вставлять эту пагинацию.
И после естественно настроить слайд, что бы правильно все работало

[Мой код на codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrLEJj)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 Slider(20);


 function Slider(margin) {

  // html var
  var sliderContainer = $('#slider');
  var sliderInner = $(sliderContainer).find('.slider-inner');
  var item = $(sliderInner).find('.item');
  var itemShow = 4; // Сколько показывать 4
  var pagination = $(sliderContainer).find('.pagination');

  // Head var
  var itemL = item.length; // Количество  12
  var sliderInnerWidth = sliderInner.width(); // 1170
  var sliderWrapper = $(sliderInner).find('.slider-wrapper'); 


  // Item Width 
  var itemW = (sliderInnerWidth - ((margin * 2) * itemShow)  ) / itemShow; //252


  // Wrapper width
  var sliderWrapperWidth =  itemL * ( itemW + (margin * 2)); // 3510

  // Максимальное значение шага
  var nextMax = sliderWrapperWidth - sliderInnerWidth;
  nextMax = nextMax * (-1);
  var td = 0;
  var step;

  $('.prev').click(function(){

   if (td == 0) {
    return false;
   }
   else {
    step = itemW + (margin * 2);
    td += step
    $('.slider-wrapper').css({
     'transform' : 'translate3d(' + td + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
    });
    console.log(td);
   }
  });
  $('.next').click(function(){
   
   if(nextMax == td) {
    return false
   }
   else {
    step = itemW + (margin * 2);

    td -= step
    $('.slider-wrapper').css({
     'transform' : 'translate3d(' + td + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
    });
    console.log(td);
   }
  });

  $(sliderWrapper).css({
   'width': sliderWrapperWidth + 'px'
  });

  $(item).css({
   'width' : itemW + 'px',
   'margin' : margin + 'px'
  });


 };

});
```

```css
 * {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
body {

 background: #EE6E73;
}

.container {
 width: 1170px;
 margin: 50px auto;
}
#slider {
 background: #1AF277;
 padding: 30px 0;
}
.slider-inner {
 overflow: hidden;
}
.slider-wrapper {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
 transition: 0.3s;
}
.slider-inner .item {
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
.item:nth-child(2n-1) {
 background: #fdeee0;
}
.item:nth-child(3n-1) {
 background: #8E24AA;
}
.item:nth-child(4n-1) {
 background: #FF8A80;
}
.item:nth-child(5n-1) {
 background: #C51162;
}
.item {
 background: #fdeee0;
}

.prev {
 float: left;
}

.next {
 float: right;
}

.pagination {
 width: 100%;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.pag-item {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #fff;
 margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="container">
  
  <div id="slider">
   
   <div class="slider-inner">
    
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
     <div class="item">1</div>
     <div class="item">2</div>
     <div class="item">3</div>
     <div class="item">4</div>
     <div class="item">5</div>
     <div class="item">6</div>
     <div class="item">7</div>
     <div class="item">8</div>
     <div class="item">9</div>
     <div class="item">10</div>
     <div class="item">11</div>
     <div class="item">12</div>
    </div>

    <div class="sliderControll">
     
     <div class="nav">
      <div class="prev">prev</div>
      <div class="next">next</div>
     </div>

     <div class="pagination">
     </div>

    </div>


   </div>

  </div>

 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: что не так с вашим кодом?

Comment: мне нужно добавить пагинацию я не знаю как

Comment: а как она тогда должна выглядеть? разве то, что по ссылке не codepen, без paging?

Comment: вот что я хочу сделать http://prntscr.com/9s3zyc. Вот пример сайта http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/autowidth.html

Comment: ну там скорее ссылки на конкретный элемент

Comment: Ну ты в общем представь.Я добавляю через цикл pagination.item => далее мне нужно повесить на каждый из этих item при клике обработчик который бы слайдился так что бы правильно показывал мне каждые слайды.

Comment: В общем я уже сделал )

Comment: стоит добавить как ответ :-)

Comment: Решил сам вот код 
codepen.io/anon/pen/RrLEJj

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
Slider(20);


function Slider(margin) {

    // html var
    var sliderContainer = $('#slider');
    var sliderInner = $(sliderContainer).find('.slider-inner');
    var item = $(sliderInner).find('.item');
    var itemShow = 4; // Сколько показывать 4
    var pagination = $(sliderContainer).find('.pagination');

    // Head var
    var itemL = item.length; // Количество  12
    var sliderInnerWidth = sliderInner.width(); // 1170
    var sliderWrapper = $(sliderInner).find('.slider-wrapper');  // 3510


    // Item Width 
    var itemW = (sliderInnerWidth - ((margin * 2) * itemShow)  ) / itemShow; //252


    // Wrapper width
    var sliderWrapperWidth =  itemL * ( itemW + (margin * 2)); // 3510

    // Максимальное значение шага
    var nextMax = sliderWrapperWidth - sliderInnerWidth; // => 2340
    nextMax = nextMax * (-1); // => -2340
    var td = 0;
    var step;

    $('.prev').click(function(){

        if (td == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            step = itemW + (margin * 2);
            td += step
            $('.slider-wrapper').css({
                'transform' : 'translate3d(' + td + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
            });
            console.log(td);
        }
    });
    $('.next').click(function(){

        if(nextMax == td) {
            return false
        }
        else {
            step = itemW + (margin * 2);

            td -= step
            $('.slider-wrapper').css({
                'transform' : 'translate3d(' + td + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
            });
            console.log(td);
        }
    });


    var pgCount =  sliderWrapperWidth / sliderInnerWidth;  // => 3

    console.log(pagination);
    for(i = 0; pgCount > i; i++) {
        $(pagination).append("<div data-slide=" + i + " class='pag-item'></div>");
    };

    var pagItem = $(pagination).find('.pag-item');


    $(pagItem).on('click', function(){

        var dataS = $(this).data('slide');

        var slideS = 0 + (sliderInnerWidth * dataS);
        console.log(slideS);

        slideS = slideS * -1;

        $('.slider-wrapper').css({
            'transform' : 'translate3d(' + slideS + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
        });

    });
















    $(sliderWrapper).css({
        'width': sliderWrapperWidth + 'px'
    });

    $(item).css({
        'width' : itemW + 'px',
        'margin' : margin + 'px'
    });



};
```

});